# Transform Getting a PHP link to a PHP echo link

Tags: php

Can someone please check what I've done, since I'm not that good at PHP yet.

```
<?php echo $_product->get_categories( ', ', ' <span class="posted_in">' . __( 'Posted in  ', 'jigoshop' ) . '', '.</span>'); ?>
```

This line fetches the category and prints Posted in (name of category)

However I want to drop the Posted in (name of category) and make it just have a simple html link.

So I made it

```
<?php echo <span class="posted_in"><a href="http://www.google.com">Click Me </a></span>; ?>
```

Is what I did correct? (I want to preserve the link inside of the `<span>` tags)

Comment: This seems remarkably application-specific.  I'm not too sure we can offer much help.

Comment: Dump `$_product` and see what was returned. Build your link with the information it provides.

Comment: It's from a plugin in WordPress called Jigoshop. I figured since it has PHP declarations that it was written in PHP. I know some code can be application specific, but I didn't think this was. What would help is if someone could show me how to make a PHP code with a link inside of two spans. I think I could figure out the rest from there.

Comment: I'm trying to replace what the program normally outputs with just a simple link that isn't driven at all by what $_product outputs.

Comment: You can just stop PHP with `?>`, write normal HTML and resume PHP with `<?php` - no need to really write the link with PHP if it's all hard-coded.

Comment: That's the better then answer I was hoping for. Thanks Bio for resolving my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php echo '<span class="posted_in"><a href="http://www.google.com">Click Me </a></span>'; ?>
```

If you're using echo, make sure to give it a string (in quotes).

This doesn't even need PHP.

```
<span class="posted_in"><a href="http://www.google.com">Click Me </a></span>
```

Is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

To explain my comment earlier. I have my plugin that I am going to stop and add the URL.

```
<?php
   //MY PHP CODE
?>
<span class="posted_in"><a href="http://www.google.com">Click Me </a></span>
<?php
   //CONTINUE WITH PHP CODE
?>
```

If it is wrote like this

```
<?php echo $_product->get_categories( ', ', ' <span class="posted_in">' . __( 'Posted in  ', 'jigoshop' ) . '', '.</span>'); ?>
```

Just replace the whole thing with the

```
 <span class="posted_in"><a href="http://www.google.com">Click Me </a></span>
```